# How to put in script tags inside Wordpress Editor?

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, tinymce, embed

Been struggling with this problem for hours!

Websites like [CSSDeck](http://cssdeck.com) gives an embed code that consists of a `pre` and `script` tag. You can embed that code inside your blog and that stuff will show up. [Here is an example of what I mean](http://cssdeck.com/post/61/embedded-creations).

But when I use that code in my Wordpress blog, it strips out the script tag. How can I solve this problem ? Also can I solve it in a way so that I can add script tags from a whitelist domains that I defined somewhere ?

Some Help would be really appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can use the tinymce settings [valid_elements](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/valid_elements.php) and [valid_children](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/valid_children.php) to define what tinymce will strip out and what tinymce will keep.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to add javascript to your page you can try the *[Function Reference/wp enqueue script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)*

Also, you should have a look at [less filter plugin](http://www.binh.name/less-filter-plugin-for-wordpress/) and [Advanced Excerpt](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-excerpt/) plugin

Comment: wp_enqueue_script doesnt seems helpful as I want to insert script tag inside the WP Post. Advanced Excerpt plugin doesnt seems helpful either. I am a bit reluctant to try the less filter plugin since its not on the Wordpress Plugins list ? dont know. I really think the solution should be something quite simple. many people are doing it :/

Answer (score 0):

You can paste (at least simple) scripts into the HTML version of the editor, but not into the Visual version. The Visual version will encode the script, thus breaking it. I tested this a day or two ago on an almost up-to-date WordPress. If your script has dependencies like JQuery, it may not work though. It depends on when the dependencies load and how the script is written.

Comment: I did write <script src="http://site.com/embed.js"></script> in the HTML tab of the editor. My version of WP is the latest (3.4.2) - I just downloaded and installed it yesterday! The editor was simply stripping the script tag, and I have read that happens on save too by something called kses. I still haven't found a proper solution to it :S

Answer (score 0):

Add TinyMCE array :

```
$editor_settings['tinymce '] = array(
        'extended_valid_elements' => 'script[src|async|defer|type|charset]',
         
      );
```

For wp_kses allow to add script:

```
function allow_script_tags( $allowedposttags ){
  $allowedposttags['script'] = array(
      'src' => true,
      'height' => true,
      'width' => true,
      'charset' => true,
      'async' =>true
    );
  return $allowedposttags;
}

add_filter('wp_kses_allowed_html','allow_script_tags', 50);
```